# asan with g++ 5.4.0 not working on travis CI

Tags: c++, g++, travis-ci, sanitizer, address-sanitizer

until recently my builds with g++ 5 on travis using the address sanitizer were passing - in the past week they broke.

I see that the version of g++ is bumped from `(Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~12.04) 5.2.1 20151031` to `(Ubuntu 5.4.0-3ubuntu1~12.04) 5.4.0 20160603` (seen from the `${CXX} --version` line)

The errors are from the linker - `/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--push-state'`

the last working build - [here](https://travis-ci.org/onqtam/doctest/jobs/134199263)

a current broken build - [here](https://travis-ci.org/onqtam/doctest/jobs/135963194)

Any idea if this is a known issue? Is it reported anywhere? Is there a workaround?

[here](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/tree/dev) is my repository on github - it uses CMake and doesn't add any linker flags. I add the `-fsanitize=address` from the `.travis.yml` config file - see [here](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/dev/.travis.yml#L357)

Comment: Probably a dup of [fsanitize-not-using-gold-linker-in-gcc-6-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603238/fsanitize-not-using-gold-linker-in-gcc-6-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version of ld is out of date - the push state option was introduced on 2014-08-08. Update it and you'll be good to go.